# how does rails expire assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, assets, sprockets

In `application.rb`, there is the following:

```
# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

I've incremented this to 1.1, but when I reloaded my page live, the old js was still loaded.  I looked at the source, expecting to find a GET version parameter appended to the js and css files, but there was no such thing.

```
<link href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What forces the browser to clear its cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version number is only taken into account when creating the md5 fingerprints for your assets.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

Comment: Thanks for this.  I figure that the staging server is in face not st to use the md5 `In the production environment Rails uses the fingerprinting scheme outlined above. `

Comment: And I had some options set funny from troubleshooting too.  Debug, compile, compress, serve, local_request, oh my!

Answer (score 2):

Set:

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

in production.rb. Then when you precompile your stylesheets using:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

you'll see the fingerprint has been added to the actual filename, like this:

```
styles-5b4f282be3720d5b1e40d9e343dfc60a.css
```

This fingerprint is changed whenever the stylesheet (or other asset) is edited. The changed filename forces the browser to clear it's cache.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be using the asset pipeline. Then include the assets with either asset_path, javascript_include_tag etc. Your get doesn't have the Md5 fingerprint, so either your asset pipeline is not enabled, or you aren't linking to your js correctly.

Comment: I'm using the rails helpers.. I'd better figure out where my md5 went!

Comment: Try adding: config.assets.digest = true